# pandas right merge doesn't preserve key order

Tags: pandas, merge

Please see below code.
Why do df2 and df3 differ? 
according to https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

> left: use only keys from left frame, similar to a SQL left outer join; **preserve key order**
>
> right: use only keys from right frame, similar to a SQL right outer join; **preserve key order**

I have a feeling that right merge does not preserve key order.. 
thanks!

---

```
import pandas as pd

print pd.__version__  # 0.20.3

A = pd.DataFrame({'lkey': ['foo1', 'foo2', 'foo4'], 'value': [1, 2, 4]})
B = pd.DataFrame({'rkey': ['foo1', 'foo2', 'foo3', 'foo4'], 'value': [5, 6, 7, 8]})
# A
#    lkey  value
# 0  foo1      1
# 1  foo2      2
# 2  foo4      4
#
# B
#    rkey  value
# 0  foo1      5
# 1  foo2      6
# 2  foo3      7
# 3  foo4      8

print '+++'
df2 = pd.merge(A, B, left_on='lkey', right_on='rkey', how='right', indicator=True)
print df2
#    lkey  value_x  rkey  value_y      _merge
# 0  foo1      1.0  foo1        5        both
# 1  foo2      2.0  foo2        6        both
# 2  foo4      4.0  foo4        8        both
# 3   NaN      NaN  foo3        7  right_only

print '+++'
df3 = pd.merge(B, A, left_on='rkey', right_on='lkey', how='left', indicator=True)
print df3

#    rkey  value_x  lkey  value_y     _merge
# 0  foo1        5  foo1      1.0       both
# 1  foo2        6  foo2      2.0       both
# 2  foo3        7   NaN      NaN  left_only
# 3  foo4        8  foo4      4.0       both
```

Comment: what is you issue? It's working normally. In df3 you are applying B,A (left) join. It's preserving column orders. I didn't get your problem.

Comment: df3 preserves the left dataframe's key order which is B's foo1,2,3,4. But df2 does not preserve the right dataframe's key order which is still B's foo1,2,3,4, instead df2 is foo1,2,4,3. This is what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like right merging would first put the intersection of the keys on top of the merged dataframe, then sort it. The 'leftover' keys of the right dataframe will then insert to the bottom of the merged dataframe.

Using the modified example from https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

```
A = pd.DataFrame({'key1': ['K0', 'K2', 'K0', 'K1'],
                  'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
                  'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3']})
B = pd.DataFrame({'key1': ['K0', 'K2', 'K0', 'K0'],
                  'C': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
                  'D': ['D0', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3']})
A
  key1   A   B
0   K0  A0  B0
1   K2  A1  B1
2   K0  A2  B2
3   K1  A3  B3

B
  key1   C   D
0   K0  C0  D0
1   K2  C1  D1
2   K0  C2  D2
3   K0  C3  D3
```

Doing a left join preserves the key order (of dataframe B)

```
pd.merge(A, B, how='left', on='key1')
  key1   A   B    C    D
0   K0  A0  B0   C0   D0
1   K0  A0  B0   C2   D2
2   K0  A0  B0   C3   D3
3   K2  A1  B1   C1   D1
4   K0  A2  B2   C0   D0
5   K0  A2  B2   C2   D2
6   K0  A2  B2   C3   D3
7   K1  A3  B3  NaN  NaN
```

However, a right join where the input dataframes is switched gives the following:

```
pd.merge(B, A, how='right', on='key1')
  key1    C    D   A   B
0   K0   C0   D0  A0  B0
1   K0   C2   D2  A0  B0
2   K0   C3   D3  A0  B0
3   K0   C0   D0  A2  B2
4   K0   C2   D2  A2  B2
5   K0   C3   D3  A2  B2
6   K2   C1   D1  A1  B1
7   K1  NaN  NaN  A3  B3
```